# Добавить элемент

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Не могу понять суть ошибки.
По идеи здесь что-то с типами. Нужно добавлять через `appendChild` объект, а я добавляю строку.

```
window.onload = function(){
    var mainDiv = document.createElement('div');
    mainDiv.id = 'mainDiv';
    document.body.appendChild(mainDiv);
    var buttonControl = {
        'paragraf': '<a href = "#paragraf" id="paragraf">p</a>',
        'bold': '<a href = "#bold" id="bold">b</a>',
        'italic': '<a href = "#italic" id="italic">i</a>'
    };
    for(var property in buttonControl){
        mainDiv.appendChild(buttonControl[property]);
    }
};
```

Ошибку кидает вот такую: *Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Верно, добавлять надо не строку, а node. Могу только посоветовать формировать строку (`html = '';for(...){html += '...';}`), а потом добавлять ее к `mainDiv.innerHTML` .